# Is there a way to inject code at build time?

Tags: c#, .net, aop, code-injection

I want to inject the following line into the top of every method of my application

```
Trace.WriteLine(this.GetType().Name + "." + "Name of Method");
```

I'd like to do it at compile time or build time or post-build - basically before it gets into customer's hands.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should look into [PostSharp](http://postsharp.org) which is designed for this sort of thing. I don't know whether it's got an attribute for exactly that use case already, but I would guess it wouldn't be hard to write one.

EDIT: Another thought is to try using [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) which is a binary rewriter. I haven't used it myself, but it's worth a try.

Comment: I've looked into it, but it brings up the same exact problem.  I'd have to go and decorate like a thousand classes.  Which is a lesser problem then adding Trace.WriteLine to every method, but it's still a lot of repetitive work, which I am hoping to automate.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you would use attributes for that, and as the Jon said, you could use PostSharp which is a great api for working easily with attributes.